# Webscraping cyrillic letters - encoding issue with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, encoding, rvest

I try to scrape the Russian journal names at https://www.libnauka.ru/elektronnii-katalog/?PAGEN_1=1, but I have issues with the encoding.

Instead of showing `Автоматика и телемеханика`, R displays `Àâòîìàòèêà è òåëåìåõàíèêà`.

Even the use of `rvest::guess_encoding()`'s first result does not work. I also tried `read_html(nauka_url, encoding="UTF-8")`, but received an error, telling me: "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !"

Here is my code so far:

```
  nauka_url <- "https://www.libnauka.ru/elektronnii-katalog/?PAGEN_1=1"

  nauka_encoding <- rvest::guess_encoding(nauka_url)

  nauka_page <- xml2::read_html(nauka_url, encoding=nauka_encoding[1,1])
  
  nauka_journals <- rvest::html_node(nauka_page, css='#wraps > div > div > div > div > div.block-themes-category.block-themes-category-elems')
  
  nauka_journal_names <- rvest::html_nodes(nauka_journals, css='.edition__title')
  nauka_journal_names <- rvest::html_text(nauka_journal_names)
```

How to obtain the correct Cyrillic letters? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, Knalwous, you are correct, it worked well! - Do you want to write it as a response? I will then upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encountering a foreign script, in this case Cyrillic, often a trial-and-error procedure will find the right encoding type.

The `rvest::guess_encoding` does exactly that - make a guess, based on confidence scores. However, this sometimes fails to identify the encoding, in which case manual trial-and-error could solve the issue.
Reading `?stri_enc_detect` of the `stringi` package, one can find different (widely) used encoding styles for a specific language.
For Cyrillic, try setting the encoding `"ISO-8859-5"` , `"windows-1251"` or `"KOI8-R"`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than guess first inspect the response headers for the charset

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(stringr)

headers <- httr::GET('https://www.libnauka.ru/elektronnii-katalog/?PAGEN_1=1') %>% 
  httr::headers() %>% 
  .$`content-type`

print(str_match(headers, 'charset=(.*)')[1,2])
#> [1] "windows-1251"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Or [query the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318831/get-encoding-of-page-iframe-via-javascript) itself via console e.g.

[image]

---

Or, indeed check the instructions in the `meta[charset]` i.e. meta tag with charset attribute (not fool-proof) via elements tab of browser:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems correct and even more generalizable than Knalwous' response - albeit I have seen in other posts how, from time to time, there may be erroneous information in these `<meta charset="XY">` tags.

Comment: Hiya, Yeah I agree.... I guess my point was to first look at what info you can get from the expected sources then start guessing after.